# Haskell | Problems with turning Chars and Int to string.

Tags: haskell, dictionary, char, show, chr

New to Haskell:

Hi can't seem to figure this out.

What I am trying to do is take a string, turn it in to a [Int] (with map ord)

Change some numbers that fulfils something (in this case x `mod` 3 == 0).

afterwards I'd like to turn the unchanged numbers back to char, and changed numbers still numbers. Combine this into a string again..

This is my problem:

```
*Main> fromStringToList "hihello"
[104,105,104,101,108,108,111]
*Main> changeB3 [104,105,104,101,108,108,111]
"'h'210'h''e'216216222"
```

What I want is:

```
"h210he216216222"
```

I'm stuck figuring out how to use show and map to get this to work without the '_' from Char. Thanks.

My Code:

```
import Data.Char

fromStringToList :: String -> [Int]
fromStringToList "" = []
fromStringToList myString = map ord myString

{-
    changeB3
    PRE: True
    POST: every Int that can be divided by 3 is multiplied by 2 and
kept as int, otherwise transformed to char

-}
changeB3 :: [Int] -> String
changeB3 [] = ""
changeB3 (x:xs)
          | x `mod ` 3 == 0 = show map (x * 2 ) ++ changeB3 xs
          |otherwise = map chr x ++ changeB3 xs
```

Answer (score 2):

I will comment your code.

```
fromStringToList :: String -> [Int]
fromStringToList "" = []
fromStringToList myString = map ord myString
```

The second line is redundant: when `myString` is empty, `map` returns `[]` anyway. You should remove it.

```
changeB3 :: [Int] -> String
changeB3 [] = ""
changeB3 (x:xs)
          | x `mod ` 3 == 0 = show map (x * 2 ) ++ changeB3 xs
          |otherwise = map chr x ++ changeB3 xs
```

You seem to be confused here. You use a recursive function, but want to use `map`. You use either recursion or `map` here, not both.

Assuming you want to use `map`, you should start by defining how to handle a single `Int`.

```
changeB3Single :: Int -> String
changeB3Single x | x `mod` 3 == 0 = ...
                 | otherwise      = ...
```

Then you `map` that over the whole list. A first attempt might be

```
changeB3 :: [Int] -> String
changeB3 xs = map changeB3Single xs  -- type error!
```

but this won't work, since `map` here returns a list of strings, rather than a single string. We just need to concatenate them.

```
changeB3 xs = concat (map changeB3Single xs)
```

Indeed, `concat (map ...)` is so commonly found that it has its own function in the libraries:

```
changeB3 xs = concatMap changeB3Single xs
```

(One could make that pointfree, but there's no need to -- especially for a beginner.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Yep.. Got confused  with map & recursion tried to combine them from two previous functions. Reached for something not fully understanding the principles behind the two... Big thanks! Very well explained!